# Neo4j import.bat error occurred during initialization

Tags: java, neo4j, batch-processing

I am trying to use the batch importer for Neo4j and have had no luck.

I keep getting the following error message:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: UTF-8 -Xmx4G -Xms4G
        at java.nio.charset.Charset.checkName(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup2(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.charset.Charset.defaultCharset(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.forOutputStreamWriter(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(Unknown Source)
```

What does this mean/how do I fix it?

Comment: Mark, I fixed the import.bat, seemed that Windows didn't like the quotes around EXTRA_JVM_ARGS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting your batch from command line use `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` instead of `UTF-8`.

In other words you have somewhere or you are doing it from a command line:

```
java UTF-8 -Xmx4G -Xms4G MainClass
```

and you should change it to

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx4G -Xms4G MainClass
```

Comment: Okay. Do I need to be doing this with JDK installed, or will JRE suffice? I'll look for that text somewhere in the meantime.

Comment: Any luck? Have you find it?

Comment: I did find a line in the bat file EXTRA_JVM_ARGUMENTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx%HEAP% -Xms%HEAP%"

Comment: can you post whole "java ..." line that is actually executed?

Comment: TBH, I am not sure exactly what you mean. I execute the the .bat file from Windows command line. import.bat with the target file names in the batch.properties file.

Comment: It was the quotes around the `EXTRA_JVM_ARGUMENTS`. I fixed it in the zip download. Please test and report back.

Comment: That fixed the initial problem, however there is still an error I cannot resolve. please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20909478/cannot-find-org-neo4j-batchimport