# cannot find org.neo4j.batchimport

Tags: java, neo4j

I am continuing to have trouble with the import.bat file for the Neo4j batch importer. I started a new thread as the original problem was resolved.

from the command prompt I run

```
import.bat test.db sample\nodes.csv sample\rels.csv
```

With some variations on the path listing for the files, including absolute paths. I continue to get the following error message

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer
```

I also tried running import.sh from Cygwin and in my Debian VM but keep getting the error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please download the [zip-file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14493611/batch_importer_20.zip), not the github clone.

This is a pre-build binary as outlined in the [readme](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/blob/20/readme.md#binary-download), that doesn't require that you have to have maven installed to build it.